# empty observable array - knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code. But I am not sure why the names observable array is empty. It does not populate anything on the html.

```
    function SolViewModel() {

        names = ko.observableArray([{
            "type": "optiongroup",
            "label": "The Griffins",
            "children": [
                                    { "type": "option", "value": "Peter", "label": "Peter Griffin" },
                                    { "type": "option", "value": "Lois", "label": "Lois Griffin" },
                                    { "type": "option", "value": "Chris", "label": "Chris Griffin" },
                                    { "type": "option", "value": "Meg", "label": "Meg Griffin" },
                                    { "type": "option", "value": "Stewie", "label": "Stewie Griffin" }
            ]
        }
        ]);



        $(function () {
            $('#my-select').searchableOptionList({
                data: function () {
                    var dataInSolFormat = names ; // this is empty
                    return dataInSolFormat;
                }
            });
        });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new SolViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access observable with () like names().